# nvm install fails on curl request

Tags: node.js, curl, nvm, iojs

When running:

```
nvm install iojs-v2
```

I get the following error:

```
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
grep: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ev_blurbs/.nvm/bin/iojs-v2.5.0-darwin-x64/iojs-v2.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
Binary download failed, trying source.
Installing iojs from source is not currently supported
```

I'm not sure why the curl command is failing. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

I commented out all the localhost records in my `/etc/host` file. Now running `nvm install iojs-v2` returns:

```
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed
grep: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/ev_blurbs/.nvm/bin/iojs-v2.5.0-darwin-x64/iojs-v2.5.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz: No such file or directory
Binary download failed, trying source.
Installing iojs from source is not currently supported
```

UPDATE 2:

I'm using OSX 10.10.5. IOJS is trying to use Darwin. I believe that's correct, but wanted to list this.

Comment: the error looks pretty explanatory. have you tried downloading the binary from their site?

Comment: I'm looking into downloading the binary and using that (no luck yet). But I'd like to be able to resolve the error and use nvm in the future.

Comment: I'm not even sure how that command does anything at all, since that's not a public published npm package https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=iojs-v2 . Where did you find the package name?

Comment: nvm is different than npm - https://github.com/creationix/nvm. That command just says get the latest of version two. I've also tried specifying the version (i.e. 2.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

(nvm maintainer here)

Specifically, `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused` is the reason it's failing. Have you perhaps set a custom curl proxy?

Please try updating to the latest version of `nvm`; if it still doesn't work, please file an issue on the project repo and fill out the issue template.